# ERROR in ngcc is already running at process with id xxxx

Tags: angular9

When I try to run ng serve command in my project it produce the below error.

ERROR in ngcc is already running at process with id xxxx

Comment: Stop the serve and delete this file `node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/ngcc_lock_file`

Comment: deleting the ngcc_lock_file resolved the problem

Comment: I had this issue too the first time I served an angular 9 application. Or better, I stopped the serve in a "not standard way".

Comment: File was named `__ngcc_lock_file__` for me. Removing it resolved the problem here too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61122898/3160597

Comment: I started getting this same error when I added a library to my workspace. Our custom build script run "ng build" in parallel and reported the error when building in parallel the two applications that use the new library. The fix for me was to enable Ivy in the the new library's tsconfig file. My guess is that the library is built using Ivy and then ngcc isn't needed when building the applications.

Comment: delete nodes_modules and re-run npm install, that was the issue in my case.

Answer (score 212, accepted):

Try deleting your `ngcc_lock_file` in the path:

```
node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/ngcc_lock_file
```

Or for Angular 9, the lock file to delete is:

```
node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/__ngcc_lock_file__
```

I had the same issue and I and deleted that file and it started working for me.

Comment: In Angular 9, the file name is - `__ngcc_lock_file__`

Comment: @Akshay It doesn't make much of a difference since it is the only file in that location. It is understandable which file it is.

Comment: Thanks, I stopped a build very fast and then this happened, deleting this file did the trick

Comment: Helped me two times angular 9 and 10. the answer by rodhan should have the green check :)

Comment: this fixed the issue for me while compiling the angular material components

Comment: My issue is if I have vscode running and try to do a npm build

Comment: Alas, it does not always help: sometimes the .lock file is recreated once deleted. Even though nothing is running besides the current build! Seems like ngcc has got some bug lately.

Comment: The lock file was in the root of `node_modules` at `node_modules/.ngcc_lock_file`

Answer (score 54):

```
 rm node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/__ngcc_lock_file__
```

Comment: that's repeatedly answered, but it's smart. thanks to make it easier.

Answer (score 16):

**Working Solution**

1. Delete all node modules
2. Close any working terminal or you can shut down your PC if you cant make sure that you've closed all working terminals
3. run `npm i` to setup your modules
4. run `ng s`

It's working with me well !

Comment: This worked for me. I tried deleting __ngcc_lock_file__, but I had other issues after removing the lock file.

Comment: What is this issues

Comment: Sass compile issues. My Sass files hadn’t changed since last successful compile, so I figured it had to be some hosed node_modules. This turned out to fix it and would’ve fixed the lock issue as well had I not already removed it.

Comment: In my case the ngcc_lock_file was not there, running `npm i` fixed the issue (even when I had run `npm ci` earlier)

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez what system were you using? 
I see that it dependsd on the version of Angular and potentially a OS as well. In my case the file has a path: node_modules/.ngcc_lock_file

Comment: I was using windows 10 with vscode

Answer (score 6):

The problem is most-likely a unique case.

1. Make sure you don't run other `ng serve` in parallel.
2. Stop current processes running and retry.
3. Reload your computer and try again.

#### If that does not help

Post a full log, so it is possible to troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: @Oleg, It seems to me there is some issue with the ngcc logic.

Comment: If you are using Angular 9, is had 14 release candidates (the most tested Angular version up to date). If you are not using some very unique setup - it should have been tested by devs already. Post your config or the full log.

Comment: @malik-haseeb indeed - on my observation, ngcc 13 has more issues with this than versions before!