# Another process, with id #######, is currently running ngcc

Tags: angular

I'm trying to build and serve my project. It was working properly, I updated it from git and then suddenly when I serve it, there is an Error saying "Another process, with id 29800, is currently running ngcc."
I retried "npm i", also restarted the IDE and even pc, but it still says the same.

Answer (score 339, accepted):

This happens when ngcc (Angular compatibility compiler) is not finished doing what it does, you must have enabled `ivy` in your Angular project. [read here](https://docs.angular.lat/guide/ivy) for more info about ivy.

1. First try to run `npm install` again, to see if it fixes your problem.
2. Try to run `ngcc` manually.
3. remove this file `node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/__ngcc_lock_file__`
4. If none of the above worked, then remove `node_modules` directory and try `npm i` again.

Comment: Deleting the file solved problem.
I jumped to step 3 tbh. didn't try other steps.
thanks.

Comment: If you get this error in angular 9 it suggests doing step 3 and that worked for me. delete `__ngcc_lock_file`

Comment: Just another question. Why do we have the __ngcc_lock_file in the first place?

Comment: @azerafati how do you run ngcc manually?? I'm trying to run it as in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69904686/how-to-run-ngcc-with-angular-11-12

Comment: Unfortunately the link to the `ivy` documentation is not correct. This is the correct url: https://angular.io/guide/ivy

Comment: Only step 4 works too!

Comment: related for windows devs deleting `node_modules/`: [What's the fastest way to delete a large folder in Windows?](/q/186737/11107541)

Comment: for me, `__ngcc_lock_file__` was located directly inside `node_modules/` so check this before deleting whole folder

Answer (score 33):

My Laptop Crashed and I got this problem after restart. Removing the below file from ionic project solved the problem:

```
node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/ngcc_lock_file
```

The file name may have some leading or trailing underscores in various Angular versions.

Comment: It was `node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/__ngcc_lock_file__` on Angular 9.1

Answer (score 11):

Fix this all in one easy command:

run `npm ci`

this will delete `node_modules` and `npm install`

Answer (score 7):

just remove the `node_modules`then run `npm i`

Answer (score 4):

This happens when ngcc (Angular compatibility compiler) is not finished doing what it does

In Angular 15 of lock file is changed. To release the lock, execute in project folder

```
rm node_modules/.ngcc_lock_file
```

Comment: I think you could convince more users of the helpfulness of your contribution if you would spend some words on explanation. Try for [answer].

Answer (score 3):

I deleted the file `node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/ngcc_lock_file_` from the `node_modules` folder and its working fine.

Answer (score 2):

simply run `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`

Answer (score 0):

deleting lock file in nodes module at the following location will fix this errors

*`C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\app\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\locking*`

delete the lock-file javascript file over there.

if it still shows the same error then delete the entire lock-files folder ,restart command prompt and then it will run

Answer (score 0):

Also if above solutions, dosen´t work it could be that the pipeline has too little space to work with side processes. What you could do is go to **angular.json**
and search for this object:

`"budgets": [{"type": "initial","maximumWarning": "4mb","maximumError": "5mb"}]`

and raise the limits on **maximumError** for example.

More about budgets here: [angular.io/guide](https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-size-budgets)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue running angular with a docker file, and like suggested here I deleted **ngcc_lock_file** BEFORE running npm install

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are having this problem while running `npm` in a container in Kubernetes, maybe as part of a CI/CD pipeline build container:

You may be seeing `Another process ... is currently running ngcc.`

You also see:

```
npm ERR! Failed at the ... custom-build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

You go ahead, put this message in google, but the fixes describe here do not work. The ngcc file does not even exist.

This can be misleading. If you read between the 2 blocks of output I posted above, you will find:

```
Killed
file-attachments build failed.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 137
npm ERR! ...`
npm ERR! Exit status 137
```

This is the actual problem. 137 = out of memory error. Adjust your build container pod and give it more memory. That will fix it.

Answer (score -2):

Just run

ionic repair

And select Yes

Comment: To get a better rating, it is advisable to include examples and a bit more details. That way, it is useful for others over than just the OP

Comment: The OP does not mention using ionic.