# Error: ngcc is already running at process with id 14828

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I run ng serve -o command in the terminal produced the below command

Error: ngcc is already running at process with id 14828.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYsLi.png)

Comment: This actually happens when @angular/compiler-cli does not finish a task. This issue is solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61122898/13287425) please take a look

Answer (score 4):

Stop the server and run `rm node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/ngcc_lock_file`.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered this error message several times.
Just follow these steps and I am sure, you will be able to do **ng serve** without any issues.

1. Go to **node_modules**
2. Go to **@angular**
3. Go to **compiler-cli**
4. Now to **ngcc**
5. Now, you would see **ngcc_lock_file**. Just delete it and restart your IDE.
   Now do **ng serve** and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Stop the server

Delete the lockfile at project directory path/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/**ngcc_lock_file**.)

Then run ng serve -o

Answer (score 0):

Just delete **node_modules** and reinstall node modules
or
you can remove this file **node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/**ngcc_lock_file****

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by Angular Language Service (ALS) in VSCode. Try disabling ALS for a bit or kill VSCode completely and then try to rebuild your project.