# How to run ngcc with Angular 11/12

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular11, angular12

So we have a monorepo that has two different projects using Angular. We also have a build pipeline to automate the integration process. The problem I'm running into is that ngcc does not support parallel execution. I want to run the ngcc command manually before the parallel process starts, but I don't see to find how?

The project is using Angular 11, and I have `@angular/cli@12.2.1` installed globally, so I was expecting ngcc to be part of the tools there but no luck so far. I'm simply getting this error: `-bash: ngcc: command not found`

In case anyone is wondering this is the error I get if I simply try to run ng build in parallel:

```
ERROR in ngcc is already running at process with id 2113.
If you are running multiple builds in parallel then you might try pre-processing your node_modules via the command line ngcc tool before starting the builds.
(If you are sure no ngcc process is running then you should delete the lock-file at /Users/runner/work/1/s/frontend/apps/MY_APP/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/__ngcc_lock_file__.)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try:
`npx ngcc -s  path`
?

Comment: what is the `-s path`? I tried just npx ngcc inside one of the angular projects, but I get a 404 from the npm main registry: `404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ngcc - Not found`

Comment: Stupid question: did you run ```npm install``` over angular project? In my project I can see in node_modules\.bin\ngcc

Comment: This was so dumb of me. I just realized that the angular project I was looking at didn't have node_modules in it. This works.